# winmips64 branch target buffer does 2 cycles stall

Tags: mips

So i have been searching why on winmips64 there were 2 cycles stalls each time branch target buffer mispredict but i got nothing .So it mispredicts the first time and the last that bne is running .In the first time says its 2 cycles of branch taken stall and on last 2 cycles of branch misprediction stall any ideas?R12 is mentioned in another part of the code

```
    lw R4,0(R3)
    
    
    lw R8,0(R2)

    dmul R8,R8,R4
    
    daddi R3,R3,-8



    daddi R11,R2,-8
    dadd R9,R9,R8
    
    daddi R2,R2,-8
    bne R11,R12,loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the winmips64 architecture specifically, i.e. how it is or isn't different from other MIPS pipelined implementations.  So, if someone else knows specifics, please correct me if I'm wrong.

That both the branch taken and mispredict cost 2 cycles is consistent with standard 5 stage pipeline, where the branch decision (taken/not taken) is fully resolved in EX stage, and thus has to flush the instructions in prior stages, IF and ID, when it's wrong.

The first time the branch executes, it is unknown to the branch predictor, and the processor appears to move forward with an assumption of not taken; thus, message about the branch taken stall.

The last time the branch executes, it is know to the branch predictor, however, the branch is not taken, which doesn't match the prediction as the predictor is assuming it will continue to loop back as it has just been doing.  Thus, the message of misprediction.

Comment: Well the problem is that by the course of the code it shows me that only one instruction was flushed and made into nope and the stall is like the raw stalls that wait for a value to be ready to use but it says branch stall .I have learned that what actually happens is that we take some of the logical signals of the branch that exists in the other stages of the code and we make a part of the Exe stage to compare the 2 values and add them at the ID so we flush only one instruction